# dual pole ON OFF ON switch between 3 configurations

Tags: switches, diodes

I'm designing a circuit (guitar effect) and have reached a point where I have to switch the signal path between 3 configurations involving a pair of diodes.

The circuit's 'out' path has the option of going:

1. Straight out (uninterrupted)
2. Through a pair of parallel diodes (symmetrical clipping diodes)
3. Via one end of the diode pair, with the other going to ground

I have a dual pole on-off-on switch that I would like to use if possible. The schematic currently looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to switch between these three with a simple switch or will I have to use a rotary switch?

As requested, the three I would like to achieve:

CONFIG 1

[image]

CONFIG 2 (note diodes must be NC)

[image]

AND CONFIG 3

[image]

Comment: What does "*through a pair of parallel diodes*" mean? Normally one end of your D1-D2 pair would be connected to ground so you'd be running "across" the diodes. You could make your question much clearer by adding a schematic (without the switch) showing the three configurations.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6dyo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Parallel connection of 0, 1 or 2 diodes across audio signal using a 2-pole ON-OFF-ON switch. (CircuitLab doesn't have a suitable symbol.)*

---

Update after images posted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftE88A.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Bypass, series and parallel diode switching.*

Comment: This wouldn't work as it only connects one diode to ground at a time. I have now added images to show what I need.

Comment: You're right. D1 should be wired to both contacts of the first pole of the switch. Fixed.

Comment: @TCassa: See the update.

Comment: Thanks - I had considered using an additional diode pair but was trying to avoid. This would work though.